# Why do my JDialogs leak?

Tags: java, swing

I have a JFrame and I open a JDialog from it and another JDialog from that dialog - which menas i have 3 windows visible (JFrame, JDialog1, Jdialog2).

When I close both dialogs and run a garbage collectior few times (from netbeans profiler)
I can see that JDialog2 (the one opened from JDialog1) is garbage collected but JDialog1 (opened from JFrame) is still hanging in live objects pool.

I create new objects every time - so after some time I have an OutOfMemoryError doue to memory leak.

Do I have to treat JDialogs in som special way so they don't leak ?

by the way
i do `setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)`
on both dialogs,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to release allocated resources you have to call the dispose method. Simply hiding the dialog is not enough.

Answer (score 9):

Have you unregistered all of your listeners on the dialog (including any of it's components)?

Leaving listeners registered can be a major source of memory leaks.

Answer (score 4):

What is your default close operation?  From the java [JDialog](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)) api:

> The value is set to `HIDE_ON_CLOSE` by default.

What this means is basically that `setVisible(false)` or a near equivalent of that is called when a user clicks close.  The behavior you observe is consistent with that.

Try

```
jDialog1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE)
```

Comment: wow I cannot believe that dispose_on_close is not the default